# How to get all mapreduce jobs' status through REST API?

Tags: rest, hadoop, cloudera

I am using CDH 5.2.1 and I'd like to retrieve **all jobs'** status through REST API, but after reading related documents I found that all similar REST APIs must specify an **application_id** or **job_id** , which means just one job's status can be retrieved one time through REST API.

So are there REST APIs through which we can retrieve all job's status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API related to ResourseManager has to be used for getting the list of all applications/jobs running in the cluster. [Here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_API) is the API for the same.